# LARK: Parsing : Implementing import file?

Tags: python, import, lark-parser

How would you implement a grammar that can import a file and still parsing it using LARK ?

f.e.:

```
@import file.txt
.....
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a lark parser that opens a file while it's running and parses that file. Would a solution be to parse text for file names then run the lark parser on them? I think you could parse text for file name then see if it's available to open and insert it's text into the string. Then start parsing it.

Comment: that was my idea too .. i was wondering if there was better way

Comment: I would not do it that way....Do you know why...? If you make a lark that does that it will most likely be recursive. So if you open file.txt and it has file.txt in the file it will break.

Comment: you are right .. but may be i can check for that

Comment: Unless the imported file affect the *syntax* of your code, the best way is to handle the import after the parsing is done, from which you can call Lark again.

Answer (score 1):

I found a GitHub that seems relevant is this what you are looking for? 
https://github.com/lark-parser/lark

```
from lark import Lark
with open('file_to_read.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '') #assumes you want to remove \n
l = Lark('''start: WORD "," WORD "!"
            %import common.WORD   // imports from terminal library
            %ignore " "           // Disregard spaces in text
         ''')

print( l.parse("Hello, World!") )
print( l.parse(data) )
```

If you want to open the file and use it as the lark

```
from lark import Lark
with open('file_to_read.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '') #assumes you want to remove \n
l = Lark(data)

print( l.parse("Hello, World!") )
print( l.parse("your string to parse") )
```

Comment: i mentioned i'm using LARK... I'm asking how to do it

Answer (score 1):

the [code at this link][1] will do includes / import in lark. I didn't write this, just passing it on.

it still needs some tweaking for error handling, but it's a good place to start.

below is my slight modifications to it, it actually reads from the files.

```
import sys

from lark import Lark

from lark.lexer import Lexer, LexerState, LexerThread

class RecursiveLexerThread(LexerThread):

    def __init__(self, lexer: Lexer, lexer_state):
        self.lexer = lexer
        self.state_stack = [lexer_state]

    def lex(self, parser_state):
        while self.state_stack:
            lexer_state = self.state_stack[-1]
            lex = self.lexer.lex(lexer_state, parser_state)
            try:
                token = next(lex)
            except StopIteration:
                self.state_stack.pop()  # We are done with this file
            else:
                if token.type == "_INCLUDE":
                    name = token.value[8:].strip()  # get just the filename
                    self.state_stack.append(LexerState(open(name).read()))
            yield token  # The parser still expects this token either way

grammar = r"""
start: ((_INCLUDE|line)* _EOL)*

line: STRING+
STRING : /\S+/

_INCLUDE.1 : /include\s+\S+/i

_EOL : /(\n+)/

%ignore /[ \t]+/
"""

parser = Lark(grammar, _plugins={
    "LexerThread": RecursiveLexerThread
}, parser="lalr")

tree = parser.parse(open(sys.argv[1]).read())

print(tree.pretty())
```

https://gist.github.com/MegaIng/c6abba4d9be87473d8d586734f2b39c9

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out I can use C/C++ preprocessor to generate a file which then I can parse :)

It is not integrated but can make it work

```
cpp -P included.inc > output.file
```